# Reset iOS app in calabash-ios

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

How to change code in hooks to reset (iOS) app at specific scenario ?
means only to those scenario where tags mention as @reset

Answer (score 10):

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#tagged-hooks

**UPDATED for Calabash 0.17 and run-loop 2.0.2**

This project contains an example of how to use Cucumber tags and Before hooks to re-install apps and clear application data on simulators and devices.

https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/

In particular, see these two files:

- [ideviceinstaller wrapper](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/support/ideviceinstaller.rb)
- [support/01_launch.rb](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/support/01_launch.rb)

I won't reproduce the entire 01_launch.rb example here, but here are the hooks:

```
Before("@no_relaunch") do
  @no_relaunch = true
end

Before('@reset_app_btw_scenarios') do
  if xamarin_test_cloud? || LaunchControl.target_is_simulator?
    ENV['RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS'] = '1'
  else
    LaunchControl.install_on_physical_device
  end
end

Before('@reset_device_settings') do
  if xamarin_test_cloud?
    ENV['RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS'] = '1'
  elsif LaunchControl.target_is_simulator?
    target = LaunchControl.target
    instruments = RunLoop::Instruments.new
    xcode = instruments.xcode
    device = instruments.simulators.find do |sim|
      sim.udid == target || sim.instruments_identifier(xcode) == target
    end

    RunLoop::CoreSimulator.erase(device)
  else
    LaunchControl.install_on_physical_device
  end
end

Before do |scenario|
  launcher = LaunchControl.launcher

  options = {
    #:uia_strategy => :host
    #:uia_strategy => :shared_element
    :uia_strategy => :preferences
  }

  relaunch = true

  if @no_relaunch
    begin
      launcher.ping_app
      attach_options = options.dup
      attach_options[:timeout] = 1
      launcher.attach(attach_options)
      relaunch = launcher.device == nil
    rescue => e
      RunLoop.log_info2("Tag says: don't relaunch, but cannot attach to the app.")
      RunLoop.log_info2("#{e.class}: #{e.message}")
      RunLoop.log_info2("The app probably needs to be launched!")
    end
  end

  if relaunch
    launcher.relaunch(options)
    launcher.calabash_notify(self)
  end

  ENV['RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS'] = '0'

  # Re-installing the app on a device does not clear the Keychain settings,
  # so we must clear them manually.
  if scenario.source_tag_names.include?('@reset_device_settings')
    if xamarin_test_cloud? || LaunchControl.target_is_physical_device?
      keychain_clear
    end
  end
end
```

The key is recognize the difference between testing on simulators and devices and testing on the Test Cloud and locally.

You can reset the application settings and content before *every* Scenario using the `RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS` env variable.

```
$ RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=1 cucumber
```

You can also implement a backdoor method to reset your app to a good known state.  This example is a bit wonky and out of date, but I have used it to great effect in the past - it really speeds up tests - [briar-ios-example](https://github.com/jmoody/briar-ios-example/blob/master/Briar/Briar/BrAppDelegate.m)  You can do all kinds of things with backdoors:  log users in/out, reset databases, wipe user preferences, add/remove files from the sandbox.

Comment: That is up to you.  If you just want to reset the simulator content and settings, try:  reset_simulator_content_and_settings. No promises though - I can't recall if this is function is exposed publicly.  You might need to require some files in your 01_launch.rb file.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your comment and some questions on the calabash-ios google group and calabash-ios issues.

Comment: In the 0.10.0 release of calabash there will be some changes based on this pull request: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/pull/440

Comment: On the Xamarin Test Cloud, which uses real devices, setting RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=1 will reset the app sandbox before each Scenario.  Locally, there is no known way to reset an app's sandbox on a physical device.  And can you please accept my answer as correct?

Comment: Updated the examples for 0.10.0.pre2 and above.

Comment: thanks for quick reply . When can we expect app reset feature for real devices in iOS using calabash ? ? . Is there any work-around for same ?.

Comment: re: When can we expect reset feature for real devices - This feature is not on our roadmap.

Comment: Updated for 0.17.0 and run-loop 2.0.2