# Calabash-ios app reset on real device

Tags: calabash, calabash-ios

Is there any way to rest app data in iOS Real Devices ?.
If not , When can we expect app reset feature for real devices in iOS using calabash ? ? . Is there any work-around for same ?

Answer (score 1):

Updated: according to the updated post there is a way to do it now
[Reset iOS app in calabash-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493634/reset-ios-app-in-calabash-ios) please see the reply by Joshua Moody.

Comment: I updated my post with example of how to use ideviceinstaller to re-install apps on physical devices.  This will reset the application data.