# Unable to install and launch APP on simulator Xcode 7 IOS 9 - calabash

Tags: ios9, xcode7, calabash, calabash-ios

I just upgraded to Xcode 7 GM Seed, and I tried running my tests which were working on IOS 8.4

My app wouldn't install, and with a bit of googling I found this - 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/51922

I have added the code below, which initiates the simulator and waits for it to launch, and then installs the app.

`` launcher = LaunchControl.launcher
      launch_options = {
      :uia_strategy => :host,
      :timeout=>60}
      launcher.launch_simulator
      sleep 10
      `xcrun simctl install "iPhone 6s" ./build/ios/xxx-cal.app` ``

Is there another way of installing the app on to the iOS simulator and running a test app?

Answer (score 0):

Please update to Xcode 7 *final*.

Calabash 0.16.3 will do the following:

1. If the .app you are trying to test is different from the .app that is installed on the simulator, Calabash will re-install the new app.
2. If you define `RESET_BETWEEN_SCENARIOS=1`, Calabash will *reset the application sandbox on the simulator*.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24493634/reset-ios-app-in-calabash-ios/24521084#24521084) for details and [this repo for examples](https://github.com/calabash/ios-smoke-test-app/blob/master/CalSmokeApp/features/support/01_launch.rb).

Comment: which line does the install, exactly (assuming we want to install if newer but not wipe between tests?